# How to list files that are not accessed for particular mins or days using linux find command?

Tags: linux

I created a file t3 under /praveen/sf and used below command to find the files that are not accessed (i am actually looking for t3 file)

```
$ find praveen -atime +1 -exec grep -iw -r 'vpc' {} \;
```

But I did not get any output, so I used below command

```
$ find praveen -atime -1 -exec grep -iw -r 'vpc' {} \;

praveen/sf/t3:NACL referes to Network Access Control Lists, which is actually a security layer of our Virtual Private Cloud (VPC).
praveen/sf/t3:NACL referes to Network Access Control Lists, which is actually a security layer of our Virtual Private Cloud (VPC).
NACL referes to Network Access Control Lists, which is actually a security layer of our Virtual Private Cloud (VPC).
```

And I read like `-atime -1` displays files which are accessed by more than 1 day ago and `-atime +1` displays files which are not accessed 1 day ago.

But the above commands did not throw output as I had read.

Please help.

Comment: Could be that your filesystem doesn't store access times, or updates access times with modification times. If you want to list files, why do you use `grep`? `did not throw output as I had read.` What did read? What did you read it?

Comment: If you `ls -lu` the files in question, do the access times match what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of `find`'s `-atime` usage is not correct.
`-atime -1` displays files which were last accessed less than 1 day (24 hours) ago, and `-atime +1` displays files which were last accessed more than 24 hours ago.
To see files NOT accessed within the last 24 hours in the current dir,
you can run this `find` command:

```
find . -type f -atime +1 | xargs ls -ld
```